# Tracking elapsed time with real-time counter

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've created a javafx application which includes a time-tracking function that tracks the amount of time the application has been open(run) for. I know about `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but I was wondering if it was possible to create a button (that serves no function as a button - I just needed to use a JFX button which looks nice) that shows(prints) the amount of time spent in the app. Something like a real-time counter where the time increases by itself.

Something similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8LOflGG8g8

Except, however, instead of using animations, using text instead.

Answer (score 4):

Just use an `AnimationTimer` to update the text:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Label timerLabel = new Label();

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                long elapsedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ;
                timerLabel.setText(Long.toString(elapsedMillis / 1000));
            }
        }.start();

        // lay out UI etc etc

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Thread class
- Start it whenever you like, and pass the current time as an argument to the above class (`System.currentTimeMillis()`)
- Inside the thread, have a loop, and a `Thread.sleep(1000);` at the end. Every time the loop goes, have it subtract the time you passed along in step 2 from the current time like this: `System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime`
- Use the proper async GUI update methods to update the button you want. You can divide your calculated time by 1000 to get the seconds, another 60 to get the minutes, and another 60 to get the hours.